# Table in Popover Boostrap4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to insert a `<table>` in a popover (details about what is a popover https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/) but actually is not working and I have no clue why. The exact same code is working on Bootstrap 3 but not on version 4.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#popit").popover({
        html: true,
        container: 'body',
        placement : "bottom",
        content: function() {
           return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
        }
    });

});
```

This is my code. As you can see, I already specified the html support. #popover_content_wrapper is the id of div containing a `<table>`.

Anyone can help ?

EDIT :

[Div with the table in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CV5cJ.png)
[Same div in popover but the table is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycdO8.png)

Comment: Should work fine: https://www.codeply.com/go/7dGG6qAyRY

Comment: @Zim Hey, thanks for the example ! Unfortunately it isn't that easy. In fact i'm supposed to load the `<table>` in a div with jQuery. And I guess that the popover is getting filled with the div before the function complete it. I don't know if i'm clear enough